# When creating a new "Coin", which ERCs should one consider checking out?

Tags: erc-20, erc-223

When I created a simple coin as a proof concept, I just used ERC20 (Token Standard). Right after creating the contract and showing it to some colleagues, I found out that I should've implemented ERC223 instead, which is a more secure token standard.

What other ERCs should one be aware of when creating new Coins?

Answer (score 1):

[ERC-223](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223) is the successor to [ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/20), which solved a few pitfalls found in ERC-20.

There's also [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/721) for non-fungible tokens (such as CryptoKitties).

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed and studied these ones during my work on 721.

**Standards**

- ERC-20 Token Standard. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md
- ERC-165 Standard Interface Detection. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-165.md
- ERC-173 Owned Standard. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/173
- ERC-223 Token Standard. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223
- ERC-677 transferAndCall Token Standard. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/677
- ERC-721 Non-Fungible Tokens. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/721
- ERC-827 Token Standard. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/827